# Can't See Winows Files in Dual Boot Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm working in Ubuntu Studio 22.04 and I'm trying to see the Windows 11 files that are on the other partition of this drive. I've turned off fast boot as well as the Windows encryption. Some files I'm able to see, such as videos and pictures in their respective folders, but in the Windows Desktop folder, the only thing that shows up is a .lnk file to a program. I'm fairly new to Linux, so I'm not sure what other information could be needed, but I'm happy to give more information as needed. I've looked into checking if the drives need to be read-write or read-only, or something along those lines, but I wasn't able to find much success with that. I don't remember exactly, but one of the articles I found needed to go into /dev/sdaX, but I don't have any sdaX folders.

I feel like there's an easy fix to this I just don't know enough to figure it out, so if anyone could help, that would be great. Thank you for your time!

Result of `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,UUID,mountpoint`

```
nvme0n1            953.9G                                                      
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     260M  56.4M SYSTEM   E217-671A                            /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2           16M                                                      
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs   709.4G   235G OS       143E194E3E1929EE                     /media/jack/OS
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     900M        RECOVERY 40645AEB645AE368                     
├─nvme0n1p5 vfat     200M        MYASUS   70FD-AFC7                            
└─nvme0n1p6 ext4   243.1G  64.9G          b4d39f72-b799-42a5-9a64-c8cefea795c9 /
```

(Edit: I should also add I did an ls -a in the Windows directory terminal and saw nothing.)

Comment: Did you also turn off Windows fast start up. That sets hibernation flag and prevents standard read/write mount of NTFS partitions. You usually can manually mount read only. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  What brand/model system? Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, one time boot key, often f12 but varies by brand. Same key you used to boot Ubuntu live installer.

Comment: I believe I did turn off the fast startup, unless there's multiple places I need to go to turn it off. I just turned it off in the control panel. I'm on an Asus Zenbook Pro Duo, 12th gen i7, RTX3050 (ti? I don't remember), 1 TB SSD, 16 GB of memory. I am able to boot directly to Windows, and I have no issues mounting the drive, the problem is just that certain files don't show up where I believe they should.

Comment: Windows updates may turn fast start up back on. And depending on your update settings, it may just do that in the background. Post this in question above: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,UUID,mountpoint` Click on any partitions you want to include that are not auto mounted with fstab, so mounted & included in list.

Comment: @oldfred I have that posted, thank you for your time so far!

Comment: That looks just like a standard dual boot Windows & ubuntu UEFI file structure.I generally prefer that users not mount Windows system partition as read/write as Linux NTFS driver exposes many things that Windows hides. That can lead to issues. But not sure why you cannot see your Windows files, if not hibernated. Unmount /media/jack/OS and try this read only manual mount: `sudo mount -o ro /dev/nvme0n1p3  /media/jack/OS`